# Bootstrap 3: Get child div's to touch parent container, effects of removing parent padding?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In the following code, how to get the Heading,`<h2>` and it's sibling `<ul>` boxes touch it's parent `<div class="col-sm-5 why-us">`, by removing the padding on parent or any other better way ?

Removing padding on the parent, will it *effect spacing, margins, paddings* of siblings div's `div.user-profile` or any nested columns div's resulting in broken grid design. Will it affect the responsiveness of the grid?

```
          <!-- WHY US -->
                <div class="col-sm-5 why-us">
                    <h2>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
                        Why Us
                    </h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Item 1</li> 
                        <li>Item 2</li>
                        <li>Item 3</li>
                        <li>Item 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

**DESIGN**
[image]

**ROW's html**

```
<div class="container-fluid col-profile">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">

                <!-- PROFILE -->
                <div class="col-sm-7 user-profile">
                    <img src="images/thumbnail.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2 class="name">User Name</h2>
                        <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil voluptate qui perspiciatis modi, velit veniam. Harum tempora ipsum et quae excepturi aut ex ratione, unde fugiat, architecto distinctio quasi, omnis! 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- WHY US -->
                <div class="col-sm-5 why-us">
                    <h2>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
                        Why Us
                    </h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Item 1</li> 
                        <li>Item 2</li>
                        <li>Item 3</li>
                        <li>Item 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you want to do separation between these two sections. please try this structure. It will not affect your responsive design.**

```
<div class="container-fluid col-profile">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">

                <!-- PROFILE -->
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="user-profile">
                        <img src="images/thumbnail.jpg" />
                        <div class="description">
                            <h2 class="name">User Name</h2>
                            <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil voluptate qui perspiciatis modi, velit veniam. Harum tempora ipsum et quae excepturi aut ex ratione, unde fugiat, architecto distinctio quasi, omnis! 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- WHY US -->
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="why-us">
                        <h2>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
                            Why Us
                        </h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Item 1</li> 
                            <li>Item 2</li>
                            <li>Item 3</li>
                            <li>Item 4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: yes, but with explanation and why it will or will not affect other adjoining div or the grid as a whole.

Comment: Ok, See if we change the margin and padding of bootstrap default classes then, that create problem. but in above code we are using extra div.why-us inside. Which are  just like controllers. Now we will add margin-top:50px to .why-us classes, which will not affect the div or the grid

Comment: If we play with bootstrap default classes then that need more adjustment or create problem sometimes. And margin-top is not fixed you have to add the margin as per your requirement. It will not affects other div or grid etc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want this. You can do that without touching bootstrap code or removing margin/padding and without breaking any responsive part.

```css
.why-us{background-color: darkgreen;}
.xcol{background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid col-profile">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">

                <!-- PROFILE -->
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="user-profile">
                        <img src="images/thumbnail.jpg" />
                        <div class="description">
                            <h2 class="name">User Name</h2>
                            <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil voluptate qui perspiciatis modi, velit veniam. Harum tempora ipsum et quae excepturi aut ex ratione, unde fugiat, architecto distinctio quasi, omnis! 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- WHY US -->
                <div class="xcol col-sm-5">
                  <div class="row">  
                  <div class="why-us col-md-12">
                        <h2>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
                            Why Us
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="row">
                      <div class="xcont">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Item 1</li> 
                            <li>Item 2</li>
                            <li>Item 3</li>
                            <li>Item 4</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```